# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound "Couldn't find user with id=new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Whenever I click on update button in my form it redirects to `/users/new.1` raising the error `Couldn't find User with id=new`. Help Please!

## user_controller.rb

```
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:id, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :email, :password_salt, :password_hash, :phone)
  end
```

## edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_path(@user), method: :patch do |f| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
        <%= f.label :mobile %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :phone %><br />
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :email  %><br />
        <%= f.label :role %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :role  %><br />
    <p class="button"><%= f.submit "Update"%></p>
<% end %>
```

## routes.rb

```
  get "logout" => "pages#destroy", :as => "logout"
  get 'welcome/index'
  get 'users/new', :as => 'user'
  root :to => 'welcome#index'
  resources :users
```

Comment: Can we please see your routes.rb file, particularly where you've defined the resource for users?

Comment: You shouldn't need the get `'users/new', :as => 'user'` line as `resources :users` handles that route.  This is probably your issue.

Comment: You'll want to set the default for the field in your controllers edit method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the extraneous `get 'users/new', :as => 'user'` line from your routes.rb file.  The `resources :users` handles all CRUD routes for you.

Answer (score 0):

For redirect_to you have to give it the path (or controller and action).

You'll want to use this:

`redirect_to user_path(@user)`

Here's the rails reference on the subject: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Comment: This is not required. If you pass the instance, with a properly configured route, Rails will automatically detect the path from the resource.

Comment: This generally hasn't been my experience with redirect_to, I've seen this exact problem before and I _believe_ that was how I fixed it.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Yeah, I added a new answer for you. :)